# How can I store in a local file more than one line of what ansible playbook outputs?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to store what the playbook of ansible outputs to a local file. I think I already accomplished my goal but it should store more than one line. The playbook outputs two lines, but on the local file, only stores one

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:


  - name: Comando para el hostname
    shell: hostname
    register: hostname_output


  - name: Mostrar el hostname
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostname_output.stdout }}"


  - name: Comando para el timer
    shell: cat /etc/systemd/system/runrestic.timer | grep OnCalendar*
    register: timer_output


  - name: Mostrar el timer
    debug:
      msg: "{{ timer_output.stdout }}"


  - name: guardar en fichero local
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/rvargas/register.txt
      line: "{{ hostname_output.stdout, timer_output.stdout }}"

    delegate_to: localhost
```

This is the ouput I get running the playbook:

```
rvargas@DESKTOP-4NPLJA6:/etc/ansible$ ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass oncalendar.yml
BECOME password:

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.68]
ok: [192.168.1.109]

TASK [Comando para el hostname] *****************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.109]
changed: [192.168.1.68]

TASK [Mostrar el hostname] **********************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.109] => {
    "msg": "grafana-prom"
}
ok: [192.168.1.68] => {
    "msg": "ansible"
}

TASK [Comando para el timer] ********************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.109]
changed: [192.168.1.68]

TASK [Mostrar el timer] *************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.109] => {
    "msg": "OnCalendar=daily"
}
ok: [192.168.1.68] => {
    "msg": "OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00"
}

TASK [guardar en fichero local] *****************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.109 -> localhost]
changed: [192.168.1.68 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
192.168.1.109              : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
192.168.1.68               : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And this is what is stored in my file

```
rvargas@DESKTOP-4NPLJA6:/etc/ansible$ cat /home/rvargas/register.txt                 
('ansible', 'OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00')
```

This is what I actually expect:

```
rvargas@DESKTOP-4NPLJA6:/etc/ansible$ cat /home/rvargas/register.txt               
('ansible', 'OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00')
('grafana-prom', 'OnCalendar=daily')
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the variables

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          hostname_output.stdout: {{ hostname_output.stdout }}
          timer_output.stdout: {{ timer_output.stdout }}
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.109] => 
  msg: |-
    hostname_output.stdout: grafana-prom
    timer_output.stdout: OnCalendar=daily
ok: [192.168.1.68] => 
  msg: |-
    hostname_output.stdout: ansible
    timer_output.stdout: OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00
```

---

For example, the task below

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: register.txt
        content: |-
          {% for i in hostvars|json_query(_query) %}
          ({% for j in i %}'{{ j }}'{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %})
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _query: "*.[hostname_output.stdout, timer_output.stdout]"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

creates the file

```sh
shell> cat register.txt 
('grafana-prom', 'OnCalendar=daily')
('ansible', 'OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00')
```

---

Optionally, add the host to each line

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: register.txt
        content: |-
          {% for i in hostvars|json_query(_query) %}
          {{ _hosts[loop.index0] }}: (
          {%- for j in i %}'{{ j }}'{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %})
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _query: "*.[hostname_output.stdout, timer_output.stdout]"
        _hosts: "{{ hostvars.keys()|list }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat register.txt 
192.168.1.109: ('grafana-prom', 'OnCalendar=daily')
192.168.1.68: ('ansible', 'OnCalendar=*-*-* 2:00:00')
```

Comment: What you put inside of content it's confusing, i'm new with ansible so if you could explain to me all that, or tell me where to find some information about that so i can understand it i would pretty much apreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: There are two *for* loops and one *if* condition. For details see [Jinja Template Designer](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#).

Comment: Thank you very much, i really apreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Optionally, add the host to each line.